# Make DIV container with list in it shrink when changing the browser window

Tags: css, html

Finally got my list working and staying together on one line, but now that the solution I found was that I can't use a % for width, I can't make the whole navigation bar shrink when I change the window size. Is this something to do with li/ul that prevents shrinking down?

I thought that adding a div with the same shrinking features as the logo would work, but that doesn't seem to do much at all. I've been working on this project for a little while now, and it's pretty annoying that this one thing is the only issue left. Once this is done, I can start flipping out the images you see that are all the same in the gif and create other pages.

Note that my website is being used to represent an essay I wrote on animal crossing, haha.

Thanks for any help y'all recommend!

See gif example below (logo shrinks fine, list does not.):

[image]

css:

```
body {
    background-image: url("repeatbg.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

.taskbarimages {
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#title {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    margin-left: 20%;
}
.toppage {
    margin-left: 20%;
}

.shinktofit {   
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -1px;
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexcss.css">
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- TOP HEADER -->

            <!-- top banner -->
            <div class="toppage">
                <!-- Animal Crossing Logo DIV -->   
                <div>
                    <img src="images/animalcrossinglogo.png" alt="Animal Crossing Logo" id="title"/>
                </div>
                <div class="shinktofit">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="link1.html">
                            <img src="images/homepagebutton.png" class="taskbarimages">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link2.html">
                                <img src="images/historybutton.png" class="taskbarimages">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link2.html">
                                <img src="images/historybutton.png" class="taskbarimages">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link2.html">
                                <img src="images/historybutton.png" class="taskbarimages">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="link2.html">
                                <img src="images/historybutton.png" class="taskbarimages">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. 
1)Instead of % and pixels, use vw(view width) a unit which is calculated on viewport and add min width to the li. 
Eg.

```
/* Change the unit values as per your project */
.li{
    width : 10vh;
    min-width : 100px;
}
.taskbarimages{
     Width : 100%;
}
```

2)Use media queries and set height for different screen sizes. 
Eg.

```
@media(700px){
      .li{
          Width : 150px;
      }
}
```

3)Use frameworks like bootstrap,bulma,skeleton.

Comment: Number one worked somewhat. After a certain size, it doesn't stay centered with the Logo. Otherwise, this is 99% perfect. Anyway to get it to shrink in correlation with the logo?

Comment: Can you help me with a fiddle or code pen. Or give me the code here

Comment: I put all the code above, but I got it to work by setting the logo's width to set vh terms. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use bootstrap and in bootstrap there are div classes that can use with different window sizes. Ex- There are div classes like "col-lg" for large screens, "col-md" for medium size sccreens and "col-sm" and "col-xs" for small displays. And in your html head you can simply use this line below.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

You can go through this documentation.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

When you use above things, you dont have to worry about window being responsive.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using images as your links, and images by default are not responsive. Giving .taskbarimages a width of 100% and a height of auto should solve your problem.

Since you have the height set at 50px that would make it smush weird at smaller sizes. Giving it a max height instead would help prevent this, and keep them from getting too huge.

You might need to play around with spacing and what not, but that will at lease make them scale with their container.

```
.taskbarimages {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Now the issue is what I tried to get rid of before. There's huge gaps in the list. Is there no in between?

Comment: @AlexaA gaps between the links you mean? I'm sure there's a simple fix. Posting your code in a fiddle or something would be very helpful so we can see exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

change to this..

```
.taskbarimages {
height: auto;
margin-right: 10px;
width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: that breaks the spacing between the list, makes it go way off the page.